# Why does block LMS have the same performance as LMS?

Tags: adaptive-filters, lms

The block LMS and conventional LMS have the same convergence rate and the same misadjustment. I am having trouble wrapping my head around this. The block LMS uses a more accurate estimate of the gradient vector at each iteration. Conceptually, why does a better gradient estimate have no benefit on the descent?

Comment: The reduction of the variance of the gradient estimate is exactly compensated by the fact that the filter coefficients are only updated *once per block*. Note, however, that the restrictions on the step size to avoid filter divergence are stronger for the block version of the algorithm. This in many cases leads to a performance of the block LMS which is lower than the performance of the conventional LMS.

Comment: Oh, welcome to DSP.SE, by the way! :-)

Comment: (I am OP - forgot I already had an account). I don't have the reputation to comment, but I still wanted to thank applesoup for the reply. Makes perfect sense. Instead of steps every iteration, you make one "big" step every $L$ iterations, where this big step is an aggregate of $L$ gradient estimates. So you benefit on variance of the lump gradient estimate, but lose on the "granularity" of the estimates, so to speak.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28707)

Comment: @Probably Please go through [account merging](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to remove one of these accounts.

Answer (score 2):

[here is a short and little (a.k.a. "consise but terse") derivation of the LMS and normalized LMS adaptive filter.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43433/unable-to-understand-the-derivation-of-the-update-equation-for-lms/43436#43436)

once the LMS has converged on a reasonably stable equilibrium for $h_n[k]$, they won't move around that much.  then it doesn't matter so much how long the block is.  and the only difference between *block-LMS* and the *plain-old ordinary LMS* is the block size.  (the block size for the latter is 1.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the correlation matrix $\textbf{R}$. In the pointwise LMS, the entry in your $\textbf{R}$ is $E[x(i)\,x(j)]$. However, in block LMS, $\textbf{R}_{\text{bk}}$ is $L\cdot E[x(i)\,x(j)]$, where $L$ is block length. Or you can write $\textbf{R}_{\text{bk}} = L
\cdot \textbf{R}$. Recall that $\textbf{R} = \textbf{P} \Lambda 
\textbf{P}^T$, where $\textbf{P}
\textbf{P}^T = I$ and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Hence,
$\textbf{R}_{\text{bk}} = \textbf{P} (L\Lambda) 
\textbf{P}^T$------(1).
Assume $\Lambda$ is 2 by 2 with diagonal $\lambda_1$ and $
\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2$. Recall the condition of convergence is $0< \mu< 1/\lambda_1$ for pointwise LMS, where $\mu$ is step size. Hence the convergent condition for block LMS is  $0< \mu< \frac{1}{L\lambda_1}$ from (1). So you did have better estimate of matrix but your stepsize is $L$ times smaller.